# File manager for linux, similar to this one for OSX?

Tags: linux, osx

I'm looking for a file manager in GNU/Linux with one feature I find really interesting and useful, those vertical panels for the nested folders:

[image]

do you know is such a thing exists?

Answer (score 2):

[Pantheon Files](https://launchpad.net/pantheon-files) is the default file manager for Elementary OS, and it can also be installed in other Linux distributions. Pantheon Files is free software distributed under a GPL3 license.

**Pantheon Files features**

- tabbed browsing
- multiple views
- single-click to open files (default)
- configurable toolbars and interface

In Arch Linux Pantheon Files can be installed from the Community repository. In Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 Pantheon Files can be installed from the terminal as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The KDE file manager [Konqueror](https://konqueror.org) has a column view shown [image: here].  In fact is it is very customizable and can be used as a web browser, image viewer, etc, and you can add in other 3rd party applications.

I believe it also has a terminal view, rss reader view, and vcs plugin support as well.